# Azure Redis Cache with HTTP Trigger Function App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-redis-cache

My problem right now is pretty straightforward: I have some data inside a CosmosDB instance and, when I receive an HTTP request containing a date range, I want to move some data from CosmosDB to a Redis Cache instance.

Right now I use Azure Function Apps only and they worked great but I can't find an output binding for Azure Redis Cache. I'm currently using Javascript. If the only way to connect and send data to a Redis Cache is through a "backend", should I just switch to it and avoid Azure Functions?

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you use something in your function that lets you connect to a redis database and send commands?  Or can your existing function call another function to load the data?  How are you going to read from redis without a connection?

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns I thought of the same and after researching a bit I found out that the best way to handle this problem would be to integrate an external library of my choosing and work with it. I thought I would be able to "create a connection" more easily with built in tools like what happens with CosmosDB. Too bad.

Comment: CosmosDB is not the same thing as redis.  AFAIK CosmosDB requires some kind of server side package to facilitate interaction.  Have you tried https://redis.io/clients#nodejs to see if there is a .js library suitable for your scenario?